# Firebase Callable Cloud Functions throws 403

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm attempting to perform a callable function call from the client (a ReactJS web app) using Firebase Callable Cloud Functions, and have Cloud Functions Invoker and Cloud Run Invoker set to `allAuthenticatedUsers`. However, my implementation consistently throws the following error:

On the client:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://REGION-APPNAME.cloudfunctions.net/myCallableFunction' from
> origin 'https://APPNAME.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

On myCallableFunction logs, it throws error 403 with the following textpayload:

> "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated
> invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at
> https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional
> troubleshooting documentation can be found at:
> [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client%22)

My code:

```
Client side:

//At firebase.js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const functions = getFunctions(app, 'asia-southeast1')
export const myCallableFunction = httpsCallable(functions, 'myCallableFunction');

//At App.js
const handleButtonClicked = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await myCallableFunction({ 'foo': bar })
        //handle result
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Err", error.code, error.message, error.details)
    }
}

Backend side:

const options = {
    region: 'asia-southeast1',
}

exports.myCallableFunction = onCall(options, async (request) => {
    if (!request.auth) {
        throw new HttpsError("failed-precondition", "User is unauthenticated.")
    }

    try {
        //My function's logic
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
})
```

I have checked that I have the following set up:

1. I have set `allAuthenticatedUsers` for both Cloud Functions and Cloud Run Invoker
2. Users are authenticated (I use anonymous authentication), and checked that user.uid != null on the client

Packages:

1. `firebase tools --version` returns v12.4.3
2. firebase library is 10.0.0

What else am I missing?